# Variance of Brownian motion at jump points

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, markov-process

How can one evaluate $Var(B(T_1))$, where $\{B(t), t \geq 0\}$ is a Standard Brownian motion and $\{T_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ denote the jump points of a Poisson($\lambda $) process?

Comment: You can use the law of total variance

Comment: @Henry That would be: $Var(B(T_1)) = E(Var[B(T_1)|T_1]) + Var(E[B(T_1)|T_1]) = E[T_1] + 0 = 1/\lambda$. Is this correct?

Comment: That looks correct to me

Comment: @Henry Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*From comments to give an answer:*

You can use the law of total variance

So you said $$Var(B(T_1)) = E(Var[B(T_1)\mid T_1]) + Var(E[B(T_1) \mid T_1]) = E[T_1] + 0 = 1/\lambda$$

which looks correct to me

As an empirical check using R:

```
set.seed(2020)
lambda <- 0.2
cases <- 10^6
T1 <- rexp(cases, rate=lambda)
B1 <- rnorm(cases, mean=0, sd=sqrt(T1))
var(B1)
# 5.000312
```